# Expose an object from express to angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I want to make a data object that is retrieved via express available in an Angular controller. Right now I can use the data object in a jade template if I access it as so...

```
#{data.mens.pants.jeans}
```

#### Express Code

```
api.get(query, options)
  .then(function(results) {
    log.info('api response received. rendering...');
    res.render('../mens/views/index', {
      data: {
        query: query,
        item: results
      }
    });
  })
  .error(function(err) {
    errors.renderError(res, err);
  });
 });
```

### What I don't want

- to make another $http call
- to use ng-init

I've tried using a .constant() but a constant can only contain a string.

How do a make an object from express available inside of an angular controller.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Use a constant, stringify your object, and then parse it out on the client

Comment: ok cool, giving that a shot now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain the whole round trip for you, right from request coming from angular to express and sending response back to angular.

instead of **res.render(..)**, you should use **res.json(..)** to send data back to angular client. 
if you want to use promises that is well and good, but my example below is with simple callbacks.

```
api.get = function(req,res){
  //use req.params.<param_name> to get the parameter passed from angular.
    <some model>.someMethod({.params..},function(err,results){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(results);
    });
};
```

Let's say you have defined appropriate route for above piece of code and it an accessed  with http://localhost:3000/api/data/:id

So in the front end Angular, you can use [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) or $http service to call your backend API as and when you need data.

```
var module = angular.module('app.services',['ngResource']);

module.factory('MyABCService',function($resource){
    return $resource('api/data/:id', 
    {
        id: '@id'
    },
    {
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    },
    {
        'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: false }
    },
    {
        'delete': { method: 'DELETE'}
    }
);
});
```

Now in angular controller create method to fetch the data from the API.

```
$scope.searchABC = function(_id){
                $scope.myABCService = new MyABCService();
                $scope.myABCService.$get({id:_id},function(result){
                    //now AngularJS has two way data binding, so use result to assign values to your scope variables.
                }); 
}
```

Let me know if you need more detailed answer.

Comment: Can you create any fiddle like thing for this... i m new to node and little confuse how to bring data from App.js to angular controller scope...